# Bounty award button has bad alignment and moves screen when hovering over it

Tags: bug, design, meta

the Bounty award button moves the answer quite a bit. Not to mention the alignment of the bounty award button isn't aligned with the upvotes, downvotes, and total votes icons

[image]